# How to handle events in workflow orchestrator?

Tags: design, modeling, standards, business-process, bpm

I am working on building a workflow orchestrator (like Camunda). It has nodes of type event. This represents a message has been received in the kafka topic which the orchestrator is listening to. The workflow orchestrator now gets the related workflow instance, mark current node as completed and runs the next node in the workflow, for example to call a related API. For allowing the same, the kafka message needs to have the following details.

1. Workflow ID, workflow instance ID - to retrieve the related workflow instance.
2. Event type ID - to understand the event type so that the orchestrator can match the expected and actual received event types are same and throw exception if not matching.

But above parameters are workflow specific information that the kafka publisher should be abstracted from. For doing the same, one way is to make the client send client specific information like client name, client event name which can be mapped to workflow ID, event type ID  respectively in the orchestrator (workflow instance also can be derived). Could someone please tell if there is some better way?